# using Android Hint as a default phone or email

Tags: android, textview

I have a simple android application that I am testing to make VOIP calls. On the layout I have a textView as shown

```
<org.myapp.ui.AddressText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:background="@color/colorF"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/erase"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:hint=" test@mysipAccount.com"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:inputType="phone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also have a call button, linked to the textView
I want that when a user presses the call button without changing the sip address, the application should automatically pick the default (hint) sip address and dial. Is it possible?

My intent function is as follows;
private AddressText mAddress;

```
public void OutgoingCall(Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
        String scheme = intent.getData().getScheme();
        if (scheme.startsWith("imto")) {

            mAddress.setText("sip:" + intent.getData().getLastPathSegment());
        } else if (scheme.startsWith("call") || scheme.startsWith("sip")) {
            mAddress.setText(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart());
        } else {
            Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
            String address = "";
            if(address != null) {
                mAddress.setText(address);
            } else {

          //else statement
            }
        }

        mAddress.clearDisplayedName();
        intent.setData(null);

        myPhoneManager.getInstance().newOutgoingCall(mAddress);
    }
```

Comment: did you tried `getHint()` API of `TextView` class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[`TextView.getHint()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHint())

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + addressEditText.getHint());
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:-

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + addressText.getHint()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: myPhoneManager.getInstance().newOutgoingCall(mAddress.getText());

Answer (score 0):

Use [getHint()](http://getHint%20()) method on instance of org.myapp.ui.AddressText to get the result it return a char sequence and fire an intent to call the number.